# how to add custom validation rules to civievent registration form

Tags: civievent, forms, validation

I've got an event registration form that I've customized putting Jquery into a custom .tpl override file.  It's all working fine, except I'm not sure how to go about adding a custom validation rule.  I don't want to override any of the existing validation, I just want to add an extra rule.  However, I'm not sure exactly how I should implement this.

I've found this post (https://civicrm.org/comment/6311) but that seems to apply to adding validation rules for ALL forms, and involves editing core files, which I don't want to do.

Do I have to create the whole form from scratch using a plugin? Or can I just add validation javascript to the tpl file?

And yes I know Webforms would be able to handle this, but this system is on Joomla so Webforms is not an option :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More straight-forward way is to write a simple `validateForm` hook - https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/ into an extension.

If you are new to creating an extension, this might be a good place to start - https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/

Comment: Thanks Jitendra, but would I have to rewrite all existing form validation rules in that hook? Or would the hook validation simply be added to the existing validations?

Comment: You just need to add the rule that you want -  the existing validation in core won't be affected by it.